# SQL Server backup fails, can't shrink transaction log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a database in SQL Server 2008 (not updated to R2). It's in simple recovery mode. Over the weekend there was a corruption that occurred, and as a result there were errors related to statistics. Deleting and rebuilding the statistics fixed that issue. However, now the database will not backup, which in turn is causing transaction log growth.

I have tried backing up with the "Continue on error" option. It finishes but the log doesn't shrink, and if I then backup without that option, it fails again. I have also tried switching to Full recovery mode, but backup still fails.

The error states: BACKUP detected corruption in the database log. Check the errorlog for more information.  The error log really isn't helpful.

CHECKDB reveals no errors.

I have tried to shrink the log file many times, but that has never worked either.

At this point I would like to know if there is a good way to simply get rid of this transaction log and have SQL Server generate a new one. If there is a way to get backup to succeed and have the log shrink naturally, I'm definitely up for that as well. Any help is appreciated, thanks. Once I get this resolved I plan to update to SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Are you sure you're in simple recovery mode?  I'm definitely no DBA, but I was under the impression the transaction log cleans itself up independent of backups in simple recovery mode.

Comment: Yes it's in simple recovery. The transaction log automatically shrinks AFTER a backup. Which I can't do.

Comment: Microsoft support got me out of this. The log was corrupt and therefore needed to be rebuilt. Here are the steps:
1. take db offline to kill all connections
2. alter database <dbname> rebuild log on(Name=<dbname_log>,Filename='<path to new log file>.ldf')
3. that goes REALLY quickly. Then go online, set to multiuser, and you are good. You can then delete the old log, you don't need it anymore.

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it with your steps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft support got me out of this. The log was corrupt and therefore needed to be rebuilt. Here are the steps:

1. Take the database offline to kill all connections
2. `alter database <dbname> rebuild log on(Name=<dbname_log>,Filename='<path to new log file>.ldf')`
3. That goes REALLY quickly. Then go online, set to `multiuser`, and you are good. You can then delete the old log, you don't need it anymore.